# Why do I get 'undefined is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to return a file as a response to a GET request using express.js
I wrote a simple `FileManager` class to handle file request, however i'm getting the `'undefined is not a function'` error ,when I call `new FileManager()`

Here's, how I try to do this:

```
//FileManager.js
FileManager = function () {}; //Empty initializer

FileManager.prototype.handleFileRequest = function(req,res){
    var fileId = req.params.id

    if(fileId){
        var path = './uploads/events' + fileId;
        res.sendfile(path)
    } else {
        res.send(404, 'file not found')
    }
}
```

Here's the server:

```
//server.js 
var express  = require('express');
var FileManager = require('./FileManager.js').FileManager;

var app = express();

var fileman = new FileManager();

app.get('/:id', function (req, res){
            console.log('get id:' + req.params.id);
            fileman.handleFileRequest(req,res);
})

app.listen('blabla',3000);
```

but when I run `node server.js` , i get the following error:

```
 var fileman = new FileManager();
                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In FileManager.js ... you need to export the object.

```
module.exports = {
    FileManager : FileManager
}
```

server.js

```
var FileManager = require('./FileManager.js').FileManager;

// this has the FileManager object that was created in the FileManager.js
```